# Array and Objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If length is passed in square  bracket notation of an array. It returns first element. What is the underlying logic here?

```
var foo= [];                                        
foo['0'] = 'hello';
foo[2] = {'fun': true};

foo[length];
```

Comment: `foo[length]` in global context of browser window is the same as `foo[window.length]`. According to documentation, `window.length` returns "the number of frames (either <frame> or <iframe> elements) in the window."

Answer (score 6):

If you're running that code in a browser, it's because the `window` object (which is the global object) has a [`length` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-length), which is the number of child browsing contexts (iframes and such) that it has. It's `0` if there aren't any (which is often the case). All properties of the `window` object are globals, so `length` on its own is the `length` on `window`, so `foo[length]` is `foo[0]`, which is `"hello"`.

That `length` has nothing to do with your `foo` array. The length of your `foo` array is `foo.length`. If you used it on your last line, you'd get `undefined`, because at that point `foo.length` would be `3` and your array doesn't have any entry at `foo[3]`.